# Error: Please install tedious package manually

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

I'm getting this error when I run my node app that used sequelize library to connect with MSSQL database.

I've tried installing tedious manually both locally and globally but the error is still there.

full stack of the error is below:

```
Error: Please install tedious package manually
at new ConnectionManager (D:\medibookr-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:27:15)
at new MssqlDialect (D:\medibookr-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\index.js:14:30)
at new Sequelize (D:\medibookr-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:239:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\medibookr-api\models\index.js:30:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\medibookr-api\repositories\users.js:4:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\medibookr-api\routes\middleware\authenticated.js:3:25)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 4):

To start solving this you have to ensure that you have installed sequelize and tedious and their names appear on your dependencies in the `package.json`. in the same way if you are using typescript you have to add the `@types/node`, `@types/tedious` and `@types/validator` on your devDependencies.

to do it just run

```
yarn add sequelize
yarn add tedious
yarn add -D @types/node
yarn add -D @types/tedious
yarn add -D @types/validator
```

then your `package.json` should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {     
  ...
  "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
  "tedious": "^11.0.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^14.6.2",
  "@types/tedious": "^4.0.3",
  "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
```

lastly but more important is to import tedious and add it to the sequelize config options as the dialectModule like this:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import * as tedious from 'tedious';

...

const config = {
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db',
  host: 'host',
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectModule: tedious, //   <----   <---- this is the key!!
  define: { underscored: true },
  dialectOptions,
};

...

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

enjoy!! :D

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

Check to see if you have tedious or sequelize installed globally using below command.

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

If you see tedious or sequelize then uninstall them globally using below commands.

```
npm uninstall -g tedious
npm uninstall -g sequelize
```

*Side note: If you see "sequelize-cli" that is ok to be there globally no need to uninstall that. That is different than "sequelize"*

**Then:**

```
npm uninstall tedious
npm install tedious
```

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

please add this to your *packege.json* file.

It seems like sequalize makes dynamic require calls to tedious.

```
"bin": "index.js",
"pkg": {
    "scripts": ["node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js", "models/*.js"],
    "assets": ["config/log.json"]
  }
```

You can find the full explanation [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11168). It worked on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading node to 16.18.1 worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
throw new Error(`Please install ${moduleName} package manually`);
    ^

Error: Please install tedious package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Sequel\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:55:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Sequel\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:14:21)
    at new MssqlDialect (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Sequel\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\index.js:13:30)
    at new Sequelize (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Sequel\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:193:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Sequel\models\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
```

---

This error is coming because

In dialect, you have used mssql
So change your dialect to dialect:'mysql;